# Nespresso Machine Tevilas Keili alternatives

Tags: halacha, food, halacha-theory, technology, tevilas-keilim-dipping

I recently acquired a new Nespresso coffee machine that will most probably be damaged if immersed. (The warranty will be void if immersed).

Are there any alternatives to Tevila?

I've heard you can give it to a non-Jew to officially own; which I would do, except that I am considering selling the machine to buy a better model whenever it goes on sale. Is there any way a non-Jew can be considered the owner, yet I would still be allowed to sell it?

I also know you can have a Jewish electrician meddle with it to an unusable state, and then fix it, but this is not practical.

The machine: http://www.nespresso.com/uk/en/product/krups-essenza-auto-xn-2140-earth

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/does-a-coffee-grinder-require-tevillah-immersion-in-a-mikvah

Comment: CYLOR..........

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1135/759

Comment: @DoubleAA duplicate?