# Does a French Press Shoulder Nut Require Tevila?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, food

[image: An image of a French press, with the piece at the bottom of the plunger, on top of the filtering disc circled.]

On a [French press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press), there is a piece that sits on the bottom of the plunger rod above the filtering discs called a shoulder nut.  The purpose of this piece is to keep the filtering discs plunged down and in place so they don't tilt and allow the coffee grounds to pass between the discs and carafe when the coffee is poured into a cup.

My piece recently came loose and the company sent me a metal replacement that screws on (the original piece came attached to the plunger).  Does this require tevila since it touches the food, or not since it isn't directly preparing the food?

Comment: NOTE: Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Comment: If someone could find a youtube video showing one of these in action that would be most useful.

Comment: @DoubleAA is this good? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcXzHQq8V7U

Comment: @HachamGabriel Excellent! Much appreciated.

Comment: YDK Why would this be any different than a metal pasta strainer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Of course the discs would require tevila because they directly strain the coffee.  The piece that I am referring to does not directly strain the coffee.  It just holds the strainer in place.  Without it, there is a chance you'll get grounds in your coffee, but it's a step removed.

Comment: @YDK If it holds the strainer in place, then it sounds like it has the din of a handle. If it protects coffee grains from flowing in a certain direction, then isn't that exactly what a pasta strainer does?

Comment: I should probably just let someone who has used one of these answer this one :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, better than a handle since it's not originally meant to be batel to the kli, worse than a handle since it's immersed in the food.  Better than a strainer since it doesn't directly strain the food.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I invite you over any time for a terrific cup of French press coffee. Although I've recently become quite fond of pour-over. But I digress. The point here is for you to learn how French presses work. And drink amazing coffee...

Comment: You went out and specially bought the replacement piece.  I assume this was because it makes your cofee tatesbetter/ it makes it possible to make what you want. (And not just because it looks ugly without it, or it's hard to hold)  It's not electronic and tuveling doesn't hurt it.  I think the answer is obvious.

Comment: @avi, your point seems to be that this case certainly has some qualifications to be toveled, so even if the halacha isn't 100% clear, I should tovel it anyway.  Certainly I am not too concerned about the extra trip to the mikva, I am more interested in clarifying the halacha.

Comment: @YDK, no what I'm saying is that it seems clear to me from the description and question that the shoulder nut is an essential part of the food preperation and has to be toveled. And I don't see any reasons for it to be excluded from toveling. Even if it's not essential for other people or other french presses, it's obviously essential to you and this french press.

Comment: @avi, I'm not sure that the halacha is that subjective.  Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @avi, the filter screen and wheel cannot do their job if filtering the coffee without the shoulder nut. It sounds from your comment as though you're saying that if it's a necessary component then it is exempt from Tevilah. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @SethJ yes you are misunderstanding me. I'm implying the opposite. It is not excempt from tevilah, it is required.

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as it sounds like the shoulder nut is not normally removable and is necessary for the proper functioning of the French press, I believe that not only does it not require *tevilah* (immersion in a *mikvah*) the fact that the Jewish owner must preform this assembly would negate the need for *tevilah* for the entire French press itself [presuming the repair was required before it had been immersed already]. The circumstances seem to imply that this repair is a halachiclly significant act of completing the utensil and as such is is "Jewish made" and requires no immersion. Of course it is clearly a case where a posek should be consulted to judge how significant the assembly is.

(Furthermore, even if the act wasn't significant enough to negate the need for immersion of the French press, it is probable that the shoulder nut alone does not have a status of a utensil until it has been added to the French press, which we have noted is done by a Jew in our case so no *tevillah* is required because they are the one who "made" it).

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilas.htm

> A possible suggestion would be to disassemble the vessel and have a
>   Jew reassemble the vessel. Reassembly would not apply to the parts of
>   a meat grinder that are regularly assembled and disassembled during
>   ordinary use. Reassembly would apply to utensils that are not
>   ordinarily dismantled.

http://www.dinonline.org/2012/05/04/tevilas-keilim-for-electronic-appliances/

> An alternative option is for a Jew to take apart the appliance and re-assemble it.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1136/899

> Firstly, an appliance made by a Jew doesn't need to be dunked in a
>   mikva. If you can "break" and then "fix" the appliance yourself, that
>   works. (What's called "breaking" and "fixing"?)