# Status of plastic drip coffee filter cone

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, dairy

What would be the status of the coffee maker cone shown below if it were to be used to make a cup of coffee in a dairy mug? Would it become dairy? Would it remain parve?

Here's how it works. It holds a coffee filter, into which coffee grinds are placed, and over which hot water (approximately 165-180°F) is poured, and it has a small hole at the bottom, through which the coffee-enriched water drips into the cup below.

Does it make a difference if the cup was used, and for what, within the previous 24 hours?

[image: cropped picture; original's link still saved below]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17479/does-a-french-press-shoulder-nut-require-tevila#comment39895_17479

Comment: Also, this seems a lot like an actual question. Why did you choose dairy in the question? I know I don't need to remind you to speak with your personal rabbi for a psak, but perhaps you can generalize the question a little.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm just confused about the sum of all the parts of the equation. There's steam, there's heat, there's N"T Bar N"T, etc.

Comment: It seems like a valid question to me.  I'm not the OP, but enough people take their coffee with cream that the dairy choice didn't give me pause.

Comment: Is this even slightly better?

Comment: If the mug was clean how could it make the cone dairy? There is no milk there, and any tiny remnant is certainly batel. Not to mention the mug has the status of glass (since it's glass coated). (Writing this as a comment since I have no sources to back me up.)

Comment: (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6598077#6598077 et seq)

Comment: @Ariel among the issues that confuse me is when a Ben Yomo vessel does and doesn't transfer taste. What if I'm making a second cup without washing it in between? What if I'm two cups removed from the last dairy beverage, but it hasn't been washed out yet, and the second drink (like the third) was hot?

Comment: One aspect has to be whether the filter is a Kli Sheni (Second vessel) - indeed - is it a vessel at all?

Comment: @Epicentre, right, but I'm not sure that matters. There's still steam, rising from the cup, which touches the cone. If the cup hasn't been cleaned, wouldn't that steam be dairy even if it's not hot? Wouldn't that mean that the cone has dairy steam on it the next time it's used if it hasn't been washed?

Comment: @SethJ I don't think Keli Rishon/Sheni etc makes any difference. The only thing that matters is Batel BeShishim. If it's clean, I don't see how it could cause the cone to change status. If not, then you check if it's batel.

Comment: @Ariel, what about Y"D 92:5-6?

Comment: @SethJ You are saying that temperature matters? I guess that's true, but I don't think it's Keli Rishon/Sheni that determines temperature for this purpose - in all cases it's still hot. (But I'm not really sure about this.)

Comment: @Ariel, I never mentioned keli rishon/sheni. And I'm not saying anything. I'm asking if these considerations come into play because I'm confused.

Comment: @SethJ Sorry. That was Epicentre, and you said "I'm not sure that matters". I'm pretty sure it's all about batel be shishim, but not certain enough about it to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously CYLOR, but at least in principle I find it hard to say that the cone would actually become milchig. In a simpler case of a pareve spoon that was inserted into a clean milchig *ben yomo* pot that is a *Kli Rishon* (that now has hot pareve inside) the halacha *mi'ikar hadin* is that it remains pareve though many say it is preferable to treat it as milchig ([source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47270&pgnum=96), based on Shach YD 94:15). However, in the case in question the mug is not a *Kli Rishon*. Probably the status would be that the first few drops that fall in while the hot water is being poured from the kettle is considered *Irui Kli Rishon Benifsak Hakiluach*, and the remaining water falling from the cone would be *Irui Kli Sheini*. Even *Irui Kli Rishon Bnifsak Kiluach* is not able to be *Maflik Umavlia Ke'echad*; that is to remove the milk absorbed in the mug and to cause it to be absorbed in the cone ([explained here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30498&st=&pgnum=29)).

Comment: Michoel, thanks. What about Zei'ah getting on it? What about using it for a second cup without washing it in between?

Comment: @SethJ If there wouldn't be zei'ah getting on it that is yad soledes there would for sure be no problem. My answer is assuming there is, it can't be worse than iruy bnifask hakiluach.

Comment: But even if it's not YS"B, it is still dairy, and it still settles on the cone, doesn't it? Or do we assume that it goes past it unless we see it accumulate? This is part of what confuses me about this subject.

Comment: @SethJ That zei'ah would be na"t bar na"t of milchig so if there wouldn't be shishim in the next cup vs. the zei'ah which is unlikely it would be a machlokes mechaber rama. (However, if you would wash the cone in YS"B water after, that might bring it closer to being considered milchig).