# Can one engrave on a utensil bought from a non jew to avoid the need for tevilla?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tevilas-keilim-dipping, yoreh-deah

Yahu made the following comment on the question posed as ["Electric Appliances and Mikva"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/electric-appliances-and-mikva)

"Breaking does not mean that it can not work. As long as what you are doing affects the vessel in a 3 dimensional manner, e.g. adding on or engraving, then it is considered a vessel you made. It goes to follow that unscrewing a screw, taking it out, reinserting and tightening it would be enough. – [Yahu Apr 22 '10 at 17:26](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/electric-appliances-and-mikva#comment939_1136) "

Is this true? And if so,what is the source/s in the Poskim for this?

Comment: Besides not being sourced, Reb Elyashev is quoted in Ashrei Ish as saying the work done must be maaseh uman which when broken in the interim stage renders the item unusable. Seemingly the Chachmas Adam in Pischei Tshuva about boring a hole in the beer vats would also need the vessel to be nonfunctional in the interim period.

Answer (score 3):

Yahu's understanding seems to be wrong.

The source for a פטור of tevilah of a vessel by disassembling etc. Is  the חכמת אדם brought by the פתחי תשובה in יו"ד סימן ק"כ סעיף א. There the חכמת אדם discusses oversized vessels that are hard to טובל and gives the advice to drill a hole into it. For further reference into the exact למדות see שיעורי הלכה פרק י"ד סעיף ד and in the associated footnotes which cites the שבט הלוי  and the מעדני אשר.

The consensus is that we need the vessel to be created in the ownership of a Jew so that the halacha of a Jewish vessel that does not need tevilah can apply. Mere engraving will not have this effect. Even more so, Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, as brought down in שיעורי הלכה, would instruct that a professional must disassemble the vessel, because otherwise it is not considered broken enough.